# app crashes when scanning array

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have a two-dimensional array of strings. When I attempt to scan through the items in the array, my app crashes.

Example: Looking at a list of employees, when viewing an employee the user can press the "fire" button to terminate employment. This should not be allowed if there is going to be less than 1 employee left after the termination. *Somebody* has to be around to run the business.

```
int index = 0; //counter for the array
string[,] employee = { {"Andy","CEO","true"},
                       {"Bill","HR","true"},
                       {"Carl","Janitor","false"}
                     }; //name, title, employed?

...

private void btnFire_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    int employed = 0; //counter for number of employed
    for (int i = 0; i<employee.Length; i++){
        if (employee[i,2] == "true") employed++;
    }
    if (employed > 1) employee[index,2]="false";
}
```

Any ideas why the app can't handle this operation? The only thing I can think of offhand is that the subfunction isn't allowed to modify the array that comes from the hierarchy level above it. Does it need to be declared differently to allow that? Or am I off track for what the problem might be?

Comment: `my app crashes`. How does it crash? Because of an exception? If so, what is that exception?

Comment: Does your code fail to *compile*?

Comment: I made two corrections to what I had typed as the code. (length wasn't capitalized, and I failed to put quotes around the word false at the end) Yes, the code compiles just fine. Other functionality (like moving through the list of employees) works just fine. It's just this event that causes the app to "crash". There's no error on the screen, it just closes the app and takes me back to the menu.

Comment: the index and the array are declared under the MainPage

Comment: @L.B: It does have a Length property. That just doesn't provide the right value.

Comment: @HenkHolterman No it doesn't have `length`, it has `Length`

Comment: Best advice/solution: do not use arrays for this. `List<>` is so much more flexible. And write a class Employee.

Comment: @jasotastic see my answer; you need to check the length of the 1st dimension of the array

Comment: @jasotastic You should learn about Debugging!  It is easy to find out what is going wrong with your code with some breakpoints, stepping through the code, or logging.

Comment: @LVBen, I was under the impression that I wouldn't be able to debug since my laptop doesn't support a WP Emulator. Thus, everything had to happen on the phone itself. I've corrected that knowledge gap, Thank you.

Comment: @AllanElder Thank you, that answered the question I asked perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a two dimensional array

Employee.Length will return 9, which is why your app is crashing; you have to use GetLength(0) for what you're trying to do; that will return the length of the 1st dimension of the array.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < employee.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (employee[i, 2] == "true")
            {
                employed++;
            }
        }
```

As others have said, an Employee class and a List would make this cleaner.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Employed { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use LINQ to get your Employed count.

```
        var employees = new List<Employee>() 
        { 
            new Employee {Name = "Andy", Title = "CEO", Employed = true},
            new Employee {Name = "Bill", Title = "HR", Employed = true},
            new Employee {Name = "Carl", Title = "Janitor", Employed = false}
        };

        var employed = (from e in employees where e.Employed == true select e).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `GetLength(0)` instead of `Length` to get the first dimension size.

That being said, this is a *horrible* way to approach what you are doing. Start over, start over right now. Make an employee class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public bool Employed {get; set;} //Note this is an actual bool, not a string!

    public Employee(string name, string title, bool employed) //Custom constructor
    {
        Name = name;
        Title = title;
        Employed = employed;
    }

    public void Fire()
    {
        Employed = false;
    }
}
```

And then do a simple count check and call the fire function:

```
List<Employee> employees = { new Employee("Andy","CEO", true),
                       new Employee("Bill","HR",true),
                       new Employee("Carl","Janitor",false)
                     }; 

...

private void btnFire_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    if (employees.Count(e => e.Employed) > 1) //Count Employed employees
        employees[index].Fire(); //Not sure where index comes from...
}
```

Comment: Ok, since so many people insist, I will abandon the array and change to a class. Thank you for that advice.

Comment: @jasotastic, There is a good reason people are saying that. Its much more readable, maintainable code. You should consider reading up on Object-Oriented design.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that employee.Length is 9.

You probably want to get the length of the rows:

```
employee.GetLength(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Employed { get; set; }
}

List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
empList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Andy", Title = "CEO", Employed = true });
empList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Bill", Title = "HR", Employed = true });
empList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Carl", Title = "Janitor", Employed = false });

var firedemplist = empList.Where(x => x.Employed == false);
var newemplist = empList.Except(firedemplist);
```